# Is a SQL Server scalar value recognized in Entity Framework 6?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a function that returns a table default constraint. I want to use that value for calculations in another table. When query my application, the result set has the correct values (check out `BaseValue` and `ExpcUnits`):

[image]

However, when I run my ASP.NET MVC application, I get the following error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Double' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

This is part of my query:

```
select 
    b.TimeOffHrs, b.TrainHrs, 
    (((a.Bizdays * 8)*(b.FTEVar)-(b.TrainHrs+b.TimeOffHrs)) * (dbo.fn_GetActiveStaffBaseValue(@staffNo, a.Month, a.Year)/8)) as ExpcUnits,  
    c.staffno, c.TotalUnits, 
    dbo.fn_GetActiveStaffBaseValue(@staffNo, a.Year, a.Month) AS BaseValue,
```

I've replaced the function with hardcoded values and it works in the application.  I don't know why it doesn't work with my function.

Comment: Please provide datatype definitions for the fields in question (e.g., is it a `double not null` or a `double null`).  There's also not enough information on what's coming back from those functions.  I'd suggest you break that query into 15 different columns (or whatever) & see what comes out `null`.

Comment: I would suggest switching to an inline table valued parameter instead of using scalar functions. Not need to run the same function twice for each row in your output.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Sorry.  ExpcUnits is a float in SQL, double in c#.  BaseValue is an int in both c# and SQL.  No fields are nullable in both sql and c#.

Comment: @SeanLange Are you talking about creating a temp table, querying my original query as a subquery without the function calls, inserting my result set into the temp table and then execute my function on the rows?

Comment: No. I mistyped. I meant to say you should use an "inline table valued function", not a parameter. You would use it instead of your existing scalar function. And you don't need a temp table.

Comment: One of the functions returns a nullable, would be my next guess as to what's going on.  The only way you're getting a `null` is that something along the way thinks you're dealing with a `null`, whether EF or MSSQL.  What's the underlying nullability in Entity Framework?  Oh - is it a cast failure?  Failing to cast to `double`, so it puts in a `null` and that's the error - it's an EF error, 'cause it doesn't like the `null`?

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet.  I found that the issue was that I was trying to be too clever.  In my function, I am querying a default value constraint from another table to use as a constant in my function.  The value is returned in my result set in SSMS, but EF thinks this is a null value.  I hard coded the constant in my function and everything works.  However, this isn't the approach I want to take.  I would rather set my default value in one place and query it.

Comment: The entity framework wizards don't get it right all the time. I usually run into something similar with stored procedures and default parameters, or with store procedures which use temporary tables and so require the use of `set fmt_only`